# I have setup the all basic plugins and driver when I run the Feature file and getting ERROR

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, gherkin, lexicon

I'm running this from Itellij IDEA.

I have the necessary Plugins and drivers, but Unable to figure out why getting this error.

[image]

Please find code in the image

[image]

```
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Error parsing feature file C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/IdeaProjects/redbusservices/src/test/resources/feature/Login.feature
    at cucumber.runtime.FeatureBuilder.parse(FeatureBuilder.java:133)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.loadFromFeaturePath(CucumberFeature.java:104)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:54)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(RuntimeOptions.java:239)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:111)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: gherkin.lexer.LexingError: Lexing error on line 1: 'Feature : Scenarios for login into Redbus
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a space after the Feature keyword(or before colon) in the feature file. 
Please remove it as given below then the error will go off.

```
Feature: Scenarios for login into Redbus
```